# Can't sing high notes in a chest voice but can in falsetto?

Tags: voice, falsetto

I've always sang in a falsetto voice-its simply easier for me-but I've recently wanted to sing in my chest voice more. When I sing high notes I can reach really high notes (I'm a soprano), but when I sing in a chest voice, I can't. My voice gets strained when reaching notes.  My range is very weak in chest voice but not in falsetto.  What should I do?

Comment: Your chest voice is going to be quite a lot lower than your falsetto. With that being said, what are the highest and lowest notes you can currently sing with your chest voice, just so we can check whether your chest voice range is indeed very weak?

Comment: I just checked and I'm pretty sure that my range is about G2 to F3 in chest voice.

Comment: If you’re chest voice is that low then you’re either actually a dude or a lady with an awesomely low voice. Probably messed up the octave range - double check that. What you experience is normal - your chest will never match head for range and shouldn’t. To maintain vocal health, women shouldn’t chest up much more than C/D5. Then you mix chest and head before just using head in the highest parts of your range.

Comment: You mean G3-F5, right?

Answer (score 1):

**G2**? **It's possible that you've misidentified the octaves**, as it's much more likely that you can sing G3-F4 (G2 is often a difficult low note for male singers; G3 is much more common at the bottom of female ranges). But regardless...

The issue here is a consequence of the definition of the registers. Falsetto voice is nearly always significantly higher than chest voice across all voice types (I've yet to hear an example to the contrary).

It's not going to be that difficult to develop a stronger chest voice, as long as you commit to improving. This is one of those things that will be easier with a vocal instructor of some sort and practice. Now, F4 is a rather low high note for a soprano. G3 is a rather low low note as well for female voice types. It's possible that in terms of vocal classification **you might actually be considered more an alto**, which wouldn't be a bad thing at all. The last thing you want to do would be injuring yourself trying to sing soprano in chest voice if that's not what your voice is capable of.

My best advice would be not to attempt to make yourself into something you're not. It's possible that you're simply a soprano voice without much chest voice training. But **it's also important that you find some teacher who can first of all confirm your vocal range and type, and second of all, help you work on that chest voice.** This is an issue that nearly all singers struggle with, so don't worry. Good Luck!

Comment: G3-F4 still sounds extremely strange. I think the OP meant G3-**F5**.

Comment: G2 is difficult for men? The average untrained male voice is G2-E4, and that's how I see in the general population as well.